# Improper integral convergance and absolute convergance

Tags: improper-integrals

I have this integral 
$$ \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt $$
where $$f(t)=(-1)^n \cdot n$$ for $$\frac{1}{n+1}< t\leq \frac{1}{n}, n\epsilon \mathbb{N}$$

I have to show that is converges but does not converge absolutely. 
I started like this
$$D=\left \{ t:0< t\leq 1 \right \} $$
$$D_{n}=\left \{ t:\frac{1}{n+1}< t\leq \frac{1 }{n}\right \}$$
$$
\gamma_{n}=\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}f(t)dt=\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}(-1)^n \cdot ndt$$
And then I wanted to calculate $$\gamma_{n} n \to \infty$$
but something is not right. I could use some help.

Comment: Why do you say "something is not right"?  What were you expecting to happen that did not?

Comment: Well, the limit exists, though it is very strange and I don't know if it should be like that, but what is not right for certain is that the absolute convergance does happen and I have a feeling I don't understand they way it should be calculated. I think that when we take absolute value $$\left | f(t) \right |=\left | n \right |$$ but that doesn't work.

Comment: $|\gamma_k| = 1 \cdot n \cdot \frac{n}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n+1}$ does not lead to absolute convergence.  You should perhaps show the work that is leading you to confusion.

Comment: But isn't $\left | \gamma_{n} \right |=\frac{1}{n+1} n \to \infty = 0$? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I iterate: "You should perhaps show the work that is leading you to confusion."

For instance, 
$$  \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{n+1-n}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}  \text{,}  $$
so
$$  |\gamma_n| = 1^n \cdot n \cdot \frac{1}{n(n+1)}  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Okay, but, as I commented before, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left | \gamma_{n} \right |=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1} = 0$ so the limits exists thus integral has absolute convergence and I had to show it doesn't so I suppose I don't see something.

Comment: @Awerde : $\sum_n \frac{1}{n+1}$ is not finite.  This sum does not converge.  What convergence test do you think you are applying?

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you.